# Regex not matching URL

Tags: .net, regex

I have regex expression (1) which matches the URL specified below. However I have problem creating a regex for input URL (see not matching). Any ideas how to do this on regex where user can input a URL with combination of http, https or www or even without these three but will still match the URL?

```
(1)
^(http|https)://www.example.com

(1) Matches
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com

Not Matching
http://example.com
https://example.com

Should Match
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
http://example.com
https://example.com
example.com
```

Comment: what about `www.example.com`.

Comment: yeah i think nu11p01n73R nailed it. THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `https://` and `www` optional by using `?` quantifiers.

```
^(?:(?:http|https)://)?(?:www\.)?example\.com
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/rQ3sT6/1)

Comment: THanks nu really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www\\.)?example\\.com$
```

Just appended a `$` and a `\` before `.com` to nu11p01n73R solution in case you wanted your match to end at `.com`